# How do I use a pre-defined style in a DataTrigger

Tags: c#, xaml, styles, datatrigger

In my project, I have multiple different controls that are mandatory. In order for the user to know that a field is required, I set a red outline on the field using a DataTrigger.

Here is a TextBox that is a required field:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding RationaleForNoInvestigation, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
              <TextBox.Style>
                <Style TargetType="TextBox">
                  <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RationaleForNoInvestigation, 
Converter={StaticResource IsNullOrEmptyStringConverter}}"
                                 Value="True">
                      <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
                              Value="Red" />
                      <Setter Property="BorderThickness"
                              Value="1" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                  </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
              </TextBox.Style>
            </TextBox>
```

And here is a combobox that is a required field:

```
<telerik:RadComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedRoomType, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <telerik:RadComboBox.Style>
      <Style TargetType="telerik:RadComboBox">
        <Style.Triggers>
          <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=SelectedRoomType,
 Converter={StaticResource IsNullConverter}}"
                       Value="True">
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
                    Value="Red" />
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness"
                    Value="2" />
          </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
      </Style>
    </telerik:RadComboBox.Style>
  </telerik:RadComboBox>
```

However, I may one day decide to change the visual indication of a required field, say to a blue background instead.
I don't want to have to go through all the places in my project that use the style and manually change it. Instead I want to set a global style that I can reference in specific controls, and then be able to change the global style in one place.

How can I pull out these lines from the above code and be in a global place? And how would I reference it in the above TextBox and ComboBox?

```
<Setter Property="BorderBrush"
                          Value="Red" />
<Setter Property="BorderThickness"
                          Value="1" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a separate XAML file containing all your styles!

As you need to target multiple controls, I suggest creating a different style for each one of them, since you might want to change different properties. It would look like this:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <converters:IsNullConverter x:Key="IsNullOrEmptyStringConverter" />

    <!-- I also highly recommend creating the color brush separately, since this enables you to change the color without changing each one of the styles --> 
    <SolidColorBrush Color="Red" x:Key="ErrorBrush" /> 

    <Style x:Key="ValidateTextBoxStyle" TargetType="TextBox">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Text, Source={RelativeSource AncestorType=TextBox}, Converter={StaticResource IsNullOrEmptyStringConverter}}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResouce ErrorBrush}" />
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

You can reference this file in your view's XAML, like this:

```
<MainView.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Styles.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</MainView.Resources>
```

This way, you can reference your styles anywhere in your application, if you reference the Styles XAML!

```
<TextBox 
    Text="{Binding RationaleForNoInvestigation, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
    Style="{StaticResource ValidateTextBoxStyle}
    />
```

Comment: Why do you suggest putting the style in a separate file? We usually put them in the App.xaml file. I know a separate file allows reuse in different applications, but is there any advantage for this application?

Comment: @AvrohomYisroel I guess it depends on your application's size. At work, for example, we have at least 100 different XAML files. Imagine all those styles in just one file! I guess that Rose's case probably isn't a huge application, but no one knows, right?

Comment: That does help me, but I have a few questions:
1. Saving the Brush color separately is smart, and will help me if I decide to just change the brush color. But what if I decide to change the style to something else entirely, as in a green background? I would have to change that in all the defined styles.
2. There are some places where I would not be able to use these defined styles as the trigger is more complex. For example, I have a MultipleDataTrigger for a field that has multiple requirements to make it mandatory, but its style should be the same as the other controls...

Comment: @RodrigoVedovato Rose has a good point, what if you want to make a whole pre-defined style? How would you use that?